# Failing to read from edge list in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, digraphs

Computing the shortest path seems to not work with me:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_edgelist(filename, delimiter=",", create_using=nx.DiGraph(), nodetype=int)
print G 
print nx.shortest_path(G, 1, 5)
```

The file I'm reading is:

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
```

There is no output.

Comment: can you get it to read in the file and print it out to you just to confirm that there isn't an error?  The most likely explanation is that it's not reading in the file you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'test.txt'
G = nx.read_edgelist(filename, delimiter=",", create_using=nx.DiGraph(), nodetype=int)

nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

print(type(G), G)
# (<class 'networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph'>, <networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at 0x10e29c150>)

print(nx.shortest_path(G, 1, 5))
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

which produces,

[image]

Comment: I'm getting [1] as shortest path. I don't know why